# The stuntman that died on the set of Resident Evil: The Final Chapter

Tags: production, resident-evil, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

There was a stuntman who dies on the set of *Resident Evil: The Final Chapter*:

> Ricardo Cornelius, 34, died on Dec. 3 from injuries sustained when a
>   Hummer used in the film reportedly toppled and crushed him during a
>   safety check, South Africa's IOL News first reported.

And

> Stuntwoman Olivia Jackson that ultimately had to have her arm
>   amputated after colliding with a camera crane.

I want to know if there was any response from the director or Milla Jovovich? I can't seem to find any links of them talking about this. I just watched the movie and they didn't include any message on the credits like 'in memory of' or 'dedicated to' or anything either.

Did they just ignore it and wait it out and never talk about it?

Comment: I don't know of any public statements on these points myself, but even if such doesn't exist, that doesn't mean the rest of the cast and crew "ignored it."  They may very well have made appropriate gestures to the grieving families in private.  The families may have even asked that they not make a public scene about it, for all we know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was certainly a response from Milla regarding Olivia Jackson.

She's quoted from Facebook at [**Deadline.com**](http://deadline.com/2015/10/stuntwoman-seriously-injured-on-set-of-resident-evil-the-final-chapter-1201520953/)

> “I sit down to write this post with a heavy heart, because a terrible accident rocked our set on Saturday the 5th of September. My incredibly talented stunt double, Olivia Jackson, collided with a camera crane while performing a motorcycle stunt and it put her in the hospital with severe, multiple injuries. The cast and crew of Resident Evil: The Final Chapter have been totally devastated and are waiting with bated breath for news on her recovery – we now understand she is stable and being carefully monitored by very experienced South African doctors."
>
> <sup>See link above for full statement.</sup>

and Collider via [**Gamespot.com**](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/resident-evil-movie-star-on-the-horrific-filming-a/1100-6446636/)

> "We were going to pull the plug on production, period; it was close," she said. "What happened to Olivia was a nightmare, plain and simple. [Director Paul W.S. Anderson] was crying on the phone; I have never heard the man cry in the fifteen years that we have known each other, I mean it was the most shocking thing that I have ever been through, that Paul has ever been through and anyone on these movies has ever witnessed."
>
> <sup>Again, full comments at the link</sup>

---

Ricardo Cornelius wasn't a *stuntman* but rather was a member of the production crew.

Given that his death (after being in a coma for some time) is somewhat more *contentious* than a stunt going wrong the apparent lack of comment may have more to do with liability issues than lack of sympathy.

Also at Gamespot

> This accident **did not happen during filming, which wrapped up on December 9**. EW reports that an investigation into the accident may be ongoing.
>
> "We are all deeply shocked and saddened by this tragic accident, which was out of anyone's control," a spokesperson for Constantin [Films the production company] said. "Our thoughts and prayers are with his family."